# Fade Toggle is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, fade

I am a total rookie at JS and jQuery.

I have a radio toggle that works when you click one radio button - it displays a set of checkboxes and the other radio button to hide those same checkboxes.

I now would like to use `fadeToggle` to make it display with a little more finesse.

When I insert "toggle" everything works as expected but when I insert `fadeToggle` it has no effect (still works but does not have any fade effect).

I have tried various parenthesis and brackets with "slow" and "1000" for timing but I can not seem to locate the correct syntax. Hence, I am not sure how to correct my code to accommodate the fade effect.

If anyone can shed some much needed light, I would greatly appreciate the help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='preferpaiddiavip_cupid']").change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find('label');
        $(".include_other_levels").fadeToggle(this.value == "yes");
        $("div.prefer_paid_emerald").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Without the HTML, can you confirm the exact value of `this.value`? (debug or add a `console.log(this.value)`)

Comment: Quick look at the docs http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/ and there doesn't look like there's an equivalent to toggle's `.toggle( display )` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no overload for `.fadeToggle(display)` in the same way that there is for `.toggle(display)` (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display).

You'll have to wrap the toggle in an `if` (and, basically, not use `.fadeToggle`), eg:

```
if (this.value == "yes")
    $(".include_other_levels").fadeIn();
else    
    $(".include_other_levels").fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks freedom. I had problems with this if/else statement. I found that this fadeIn/fadeOut was just a poor transition that was difficult to detect unless you did it over a long time. I took your if/else and changed the "fadeIn" and "fadeOut" to toggle for both instances and now it works great. Thanks for putting me on the correct path. I appreciate your help!